# SAPUI5 Table total row at bottom

Tags: xml, sapui5

I am using a sap.ui.table to display columns of data. There are only 12 rows of data - the data is loaded from an ajax call to a database. I would like a total row at the bottom of the columns. I can't find any examples that show totals for the columns.

Here is a small snippet of my table in the XML view.

```
        <table:Table 
        id="CompRecs" 
        visibleRowCount="12"  
        visible="true" 
        rows="{
            path:'/yearInfo/'
        }"
        navigationMode="Paginator">
           <table:toolbar>
              <Toolbar>
                <Label id="recText"  text="Comparing " ></Label>
                <Input id="startYear"  width="15%" value="{/startYear}"/>
                <Label id="selText"   text=" to "></Label>
                <Input id="endYear"  width="15%" value="{/endYear}"/>
                <Button text="Compare Years" press="findRecs"/>
              </Toolbar>
           </table:toolbar>
           <table:columns>
                <table:Column >
                    <Label text="Month" />
                    <table:template>
                        <Text text="{path: 'monthECC',formatter: 'controllers.Formatter.month'}"></Text>
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column> 
                <table:Column >
                    <Label text="Classified Products/Components" />
                    <table:template>
                        <Text text="{classProductsA} ({classProductsB})"></Text>
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column> 
                <table:Column  >
                    <Label text="Classified Business Partners" />
                    <table:template>
                        <Text text="{classPartnersA} ({classPartnersB})"></Text>
                    </table:template>
                </table:Column>
            </table:columns> 
       </table:Table>
```

What I would like to do is to have a total at the bottom for columns such as the Classified Products and Partners....these columns are showing two values - one for the current year, and one for the previous year ('classproductsA' = year 1, 'classproductsB' = year 2).

So it should look something similar to:

```
Month      Classified Products          Classified Partners
January         3 (5)                       4 (7)
February        4 (3)                       5 (1)

Totals:         7 (8)                       9 (8)
```

I haven't found any examples that I can try.

EDIT: Sample data:

```
{"yearInfo":
[{"monthECC":"1","classProductsA":"17","classProductsB":"140","classPartnersA":"1161","classPartnersB":"1116"},
{"monthECC":"2","classProductsA":"37","classProductsB":"66","classPartnersA":"1389","classPartnersB":"1112"},    
{"monthECC":"3","classProductsA":"60","classProductsB":"66","classPartnersA":"2111","classPartnersB":"1905"}]
```

Shows 3 'months' of data to match XML columns above. So would want:

```
Month      Classified Products          Classified Partners
January         17 (140)                      1161 (1116)
February        37 (66)                       66 (1389)
March           60 (66)                       2111 (1905)

Totals:         114 (272)                     3338 (4410)
```

Answer (score 2):

Did you try writing a footer for the table? The breadcrumb example of table in the UI5 Explored project has this code. You will simply have to write a footer aggregation.
Now to write the count , you will have to specify the elements you require as parts and then put a formatter to get the results.
For your data, to get the classProductsA total in a label. Here is the code in js. (too bad with xml but sure will work the same way)

```
var totalLabel = new sap.m.Label({
'text':
{path:'/yearInfo',
     formatter:function(fullArray){
            var classProductsATotal = 0;
           $.each(fullArray ,function(singleElement){
            classProductsATotal = classProductsATotal+singleElement.classProductsA;
                 }); //end of $each.
    return classProductsATotal;
}});
```

The formatter is the function you will have to look for.
The path is set to `/yearInfo` which will mean that it will give the full array as input to the formatter function .Once its there,you can always do a loop to get the total.

Comment: I tried looking into the footer, but couldn't find an example to know how to lay it out or what to do. I will try looking at the one you mention and see if it helps.

Comment: the breadcrumb example didn't really help, since it only has a button there. I don't think I know enough to know how to go about writing the aggregation to get the total and the formatter. I think if I could see an example of doing something like what I want that I could follow it to make it work for my table.

Comment: Please post your sample data so that I can show you the sample on formatter for calculating total.

Comment: thanks. I will try your suggestion....I appreciate your help. I'll have to see if there is an easy way to do this for each column (I have about 9 that need totals) so it would be a pain to have to do that nine times :)  I was looking yesterday to see if there was something at the Column level that would do the summing, but couldn't find anything -  I am hopeful your solution will work.

Comment: ok, so I added your code to my controller and now have a somewhat stupid question....how do I get it to display in the footer? And does the table footer, keep the same number of columns or do I have to somewhat create the columns in the footer? Sorry, for the questions but since I haven't used the footer before and am somewhat new to SAPUI5, I am a little confused.

Comment: I got your solution to work kind of. I tried adding a Label in my footer using your formatter. The total value does show, but I don't seem to be able to include anything other than the Label - for instance, if I want to include another Label for another column. As I was searching around, I found the  Developer's Guide and it 'seems' that you can specify a footer for a Column, but i haven't gotten it to work. From guide - "footer" Any control can be assigned to be displayed in the column footer. If at least one column has a footer definition, then the footer line is displayed for all columns.